# T4i battery charged by USB?

Tags: canon

I would like to charge my T4i battery in camera with a USB cable. Can I do that or do I need a special USB cable? If so is there a solar charger it can connect to? It's for a 14-day river trip.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know no Canon DSLR can do this (charge battery via USB).

But you can buy additional batteries and charge them via solar panel. There are different options for USB chargers, [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00V5ORSY6) is one example for LP-E8.

P.S. No affiliate with manufacturer and seller

Answer (score 1):

You can't charge your camera's battery in-camera, at all. There is no battery charger circuitry in the camera at all. In order to charge the battery, you must remove it and charge it with an external battery charger.